# What is the best method of creating a server side timer in Java?

Tags: java, timer

I am trying to make it so when a player is added to featured this timer counts down :P i have to init it in my main server so the timer will continue to count down even when players are offline. The timer needs to check if a player is assigned to a featured spot then begin counting down if not return of course :p

[S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pqS2.jpg)

```
    public static void featuredItems(Player c) {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter time = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H"); //Gets hours
    int currentTime = Integer.parseInt(time.format(now));
    int start1 = 22017, id = 0, totalSales = 0;

    List<ListedItem> items = getSalesForPlayer(c.getName().toLowerCase());
        c.getPA().sendFrame126("Featured Items", 22004);
        
        
        for (ListedItem sale : items) {
            if (sale.soldAll())
                continue;
            c.getPA().sendFrame126(sale.getSeller(), start1);//this calls for the top variable in featured shops
        start1++;
        c.getPA().sendFrame126("Time: " + (24 - currentTime) + " (H)", start1);//this calls for bottom variable
        start1 ++;
        start1 ++;
        totalSales++;
        Misc.print("Name:" +c.getName().toLowerCase());
        c.lastTimeForPost = now.getDayOfMonth();
        Misc.print("Time:" +c.lastTimeForPost);
        if (totalSales == 10) {
             Misc.print("Reached 10 featured sales");
            break;
        }
        }
}


    private static final Runnable SERVER_TASKS = () -> {
    try {


        itemHandler.process();
        playerHandler.process();
        npcHandler.process();
        shopHandler.process();
        Highpkarena.process();
        Lowpkarena.process();
        globalObjects.pulse();
        CycleEventHandler.getSingleton().process();
        events.process();
        serverData.processQueue();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        t.getCause();
        t.getMessage();
        t.fillInStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Server tasks - Check for error");
        PlayerHandler.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(PlayerSave::save);
    }
};
```

i know i have to call it in my server main but just not sure how to do it or load it :p

Comment: You should never have an actual running timer on a server. Instead, store (however you're storing things) the last timestamp (and use `Instant.now()`), and calculate the time elapsed whenever you need it (such as `Duration.between(previous, now())`).

Comment: im thinking i should just get rid of that local date and time.I think i went about it the wrong way

Comment: right now the time is loading 24 hours - whatever time it is i need it o display a timer counting down in hours like i wanna make someone a featured player for 8 hours and it to display counting down :p 7hrs 59:59 seconds

Comment: You don't do that countdown on the server. It lives in whatever client you have, such as an Android or JavaScript program.

Comment: well i definitely want the timer saved server side that way it updates when the client logs off? its a shop that keeps buying and selling player items even when they are offline :p which is done server sided